# Parse JSON data is returning null value

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7

I am getting JSON data with below code as string. But really very confusing to solve this

```
NSString *htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"userdetail :%@" , htmlSTR);
```

But i need to parse the Id only.

I parsed with the code of

```
NSDictionary *JsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.receivedData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
    NSLog(@"json %@",jsonArr1);

    NSString *string=[JsonDict valueForKey:@"Id"];
```

But its returning null value for string, even for integer it is returning numeric zero

```
 userdetail : {"Country":"Afghanistan","CreatedBy":"raje@gmail.com","FirstName":"rajeev","Gender":"M","LastName":"leader","ModifiedBy":"raje@gmail.com","Password":"asdf","emails":"raje@gmail.com","id":32}
```

This is the first time am trying this thing, help me to solve this.Sorry for bad formatting.

Comment: The JSON you posted is invalid.

Comment: Change your key `Id` to `id` and try!

Comment: what is userdetail in your josh?try this if it is object     NSString *temp=[[json objectForKey:@"userdetail"]valueForKey:@"id"];

Comment: userdetail is a json string . show first line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only change this line .

```
 NSString *string=[JsonDict valueForKey:@"Id"];
```

**TO**

```
 NSString *string=[JsonDict valueForKey:@"id"];
```

Hope this works for you.